# Is there an abstract word for the environment in which a vehicle can move?

Tags: terminology, hypernyms, programming

I am looking for a word (or short construct of words) that could be used to refer to things that a given vehicle could traverse: "sky, land, water. etc."

To give an analogue, I can refer to "gasoline, diesel, electricity, rocket, etc." as "fuels"

In my specific case, I can't use "environment" because it's being used to describe other things in the same work, and would become ambiguous.

Comment: Are you looking for *terrain*?

Comment: that, or some modification of it, could work! why not make it an answer so I can give props?

Comment: Thanks & happy to help. I'm curious to see if there will be other/better responses!

Comment: +1 great question: however I think you request a "general word for the environment..." rather than an "abstract word for the environment..."

Comment: @JackRyan: possibly, but isn't an abstraction a generalised idea already? (I'm a programmer, not an englishman or otherwise part of the English speaking population of the world)

Comment: The military might use the term "theater" here.

Comment: @mkoistinen : That's more a political-geographical label than a habitat-geographical one.

Comment: name the variable questions are off topic per the [help].

Comment: @MετάEd: how does linking to a listing of a million questions help anyone validate your point?

Comment: Looking at it from a different (user-) perspective may be of help. See also my answer below.

Comment: Edited and re-opened. The programming context is a red herring.  This is less a special-case naming problem than a legitimate diction question that happens to be for a programming need.  I edited out the programming, which brings it into the site guidelines without changing the OP's basic question.

Comment: Thanks everybody for taking the time to read, research and answer my question. It is much appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would suggest [medium](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/medium)

> 2: a means of effecting or conveying something: as a surrounding or enveloping substance

Comment: +1 even though I can't (yet) see a way of using it, too generic for my use case

Comment: @Kris you mark the answer you accept by clicking the "tick" button, and the users will vote on the answers they think are best for them.

Comment: @user1306322: I know, I'm just not ready to do that yet.

Comment: @Kris In fact I wasn't thrilled with it either.  See my last comment under "terrain."

Comment: Medium for... Cars?  Magic?  Electricity?  The ambiguity of this term (which will require a second qualifying word) seems to negate its usefulness with the intended meaning in the question.

Comment: The eventual term would probably be "travel medium". A _short_ construct of unambiguous words is as good as a single term if there is no single term that is better than the short construct. Though I still feel like travel medium could also refer to the substance that allows the vehicle to act like a vehicle and could possible be confused with "fuel". feel free to prove me wrong though. Travel*able* medium/media (amphibious vehicles?) maybe?

Comment: The two comments above are **not** mine. That said, *medium*, though correct when looked from the way OP has formulated the question, is not used with reference to the 'mode of transportation.' See my answer below.

Comment: It easily gets confusing when there's more than one person with the same name :) I (the OP) am still somewhat conflicted but people more knowledgable than me seem to agree that this is the best "tool for the job" so for now I'll stick with medium in the form of "TravelMedium".

Answer (score 15):

Would *terrain* fit your needs?

> ter·rain
>   /təˈrān/
>   Noun:
>   An area of land or the particular features of it.

Another, albeit longer, option would be *topography*

> Noun:
>
> 1. a precise description of a place
>      a detailed graphic representation of the surface features of a place or object
> 2. the features themselves (the terrain)
> 3. the surveying of the features

**EDIT:**
With suggestion from a comment I've added the following, from m-w.com

> *milieu*
>
> noun: the physical or social setting in which something occurs or develops : environment

Comment: Terrain is a generalization of any class of land, but does not seem to apply to either water or air/space.

Comment: @JackRyan Within the context of video games, "terrain" is used (almost everywhere) for surfaces the players can traverse, provided there are no other obstacles (like a wall or building).  This includes land and, often, water (some games don't allow players in the water), although I'm not so sure about air/space.

Comment: @Izkata I have no doubt it's used, I'm questioning whether or not it's use is appropriate.  This definition and the etymology firmly (pun intended) point to solid earth rather gaseous or liquid material.

Comment: @Jacobm001 In fact "terrain" in M-W links to what might be an even more appropriate answer: [Milieu](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/milieu)

Comment: @JackRyan I'm bringing it up because the question specifically asks about in the context of a programming problem, which sounds like a video game of some sort to me.  When thought of that way, almost every other answer just sounds bizarre and (in one or two cases) pretentious - and in others, ambiguous ("domain", for example, is much more broad than makes sense - you'd need to qualify what it is the domain _of_, negating the advantage of the term).

Comment: @JackRyan: Added as an edit.

Comment: *Terrain* has nothing to do with the context. Check dictionaries.

Comment: Terrain does seem like the most obvious choice at first, but it ends up feeling wrong. Also, as an aside, the context isn't a video game but a collection of types with wich to construct tests for study purposes.

Answer (score 10):

This meaning of the word **domain** might be appropriate:

> A district or region under rule, control, or influence, or contained within certain limits; realm; sphere of activity, influence, or dominion.

(Source: [OED, 3b](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/56649?rskey=89td22&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid))

Comment: This is what I would have suggested too. I've specifically seen it used to refer to land, sea, or air.

Answer (score 4):

**Element**.

(Webster's:

> **three:**  a natural habitat, sphere of activity, or environment... )

However, that is not to say that using this word would sound natural in every possible context.

Also, I wish the auto-correct device wouldn't keep renumbering - that's Webster's sense 3 for 'element'.

Comment: +1 in fact 1a from m-w.com: "any of the four substances air, water, fire, and earth formerly believed to compose the physical universe."  If donation was an option I would put all of the votes accrued from "medium" here.

Comment: In spite of the plaudits, I don't agree that these are the same polysemes, Jack. Closely related, yes. But the sense I was thinking of appears say in 'He's in his element when he's swimming / singing / parsing sentences.' This would sound OK with 'The new tank is in its element surging through shallow bogs.' However, as head of a table: Element: air / deep water / shallow water / shallow marsh / sandy desert / stony desert ... - it sounds distinctly odd.

Comment: I admit I like "Element", especially with the added reasoning. On its own however, it remains too ambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

Consider *[environs](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/environs)*.

It's used in a similar sense to environment, but has the connotation of being more localized. One could say *a vehicle moves through its environs*.

Answer (score 2):

I know it doesn't get any more abstract than these two but what about **space** or **area**.

If this is to be used in a programming sense then, personally I would go for something along the lines of **driver-zone** or **go-zone** (as opposed to the commonly used term *no-go zone*).

Answer (score 1):

Element is the best word. You must have heard five elements of earth(i.e. Land, Fire, Water, Air, Sky or vacuum).

Comment: Yes but on its own it is much too ambiguous. Almost everything else in scope can also be said to be an element of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is wrong, but my brain dredged up "substrate"

Comment: But medium is better.

Answer (score 0):

[Mode of transport(ation)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_of_transportation)

> Mode of transport (or means of transport or transport mode or transport modality or form of transport) is a term used to distinguish substantially different ways to perform transport. The most dominant modes of transport are aviation, land transport, which includes rail, road and off-road transport, and ship transport. Other modes also exist, including pipelines, cable transport, and space transport. Human-powered transport and animal-powered transport are sometimes regarded as their own mode, but these normally also fall into the other categories.

For the OP's given example, just ***mode*** should serve the purpose as it would be self-explanatory in context.

Also discussed under [Transport](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport) on Wiki.

Comment: Mode of transportation would be flight, not sky though right?

Comment: @Kris Mode of transportation would be **air/ sea/ land ...** not *flight* -- study the links in the answer. HTH.

Comment: I did and the first thing i read was "...is a term used to distinguish substantially different **ways to perform**..." (emphasis mine) then further on it groups those "ways" by the types of things in my original list. I'm still think it's too ambiguous. Mode is closer to method (of doing something) than to substance (of doing that thing in/on/over/under)

Comment: I would like to capture: flight, train, bus; with the same name. What would be the correct word and possible difference: mode vs. mean vs. type of transport?